# Average of Rnd Num in a loop java

Tags: java

I'm stuck trying to calculate the average when I generate 3 random integers between 1 and 20. I have to round the average to int and repeat it 10000 times. When I test my program repeating 2 times, I am getting the output of:

```
Number is :18
Number is :14
Number is :2
sum is: 34
Average is: 11

Number is :13
Number is :3
Number is :6
sum is: 56
Average is: 18
```

However, the average should be the average of just the 3 numbers. Here, the second loop adds the sum of the first loop to the sum of the second making the average wrong (Sum:34+22=56). I want it to be 22 so the average for that would be 7. I notice the problem might be this line,  sum += n;  , but I don't know another way to add the 3 number for each loop to get the average.

```
package Histogram;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int N = 2;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n;
        int average;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
                System.out.println("Number is :" + n);
                sum += n;
            }
            average = sum / 3;

        System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could reset `sum` to 0 after you calculated the average.

Comment: You have to make sure you initialize `sum` to 0 in the right place.

Comment: In fact you shouldn't even declare n, sum and average outside the outer loop. n should be declared inside the inner loop, and sum and average should be declared inside the outer loop. The next step is to extract the body of the inner loop, computing the average, into its own method. Always keep the scope of your variables as narrow as possible. Give a single responsibility to your methods.

Answer (score 1):

> the average should be the average of just the 3 numbers. Here, the
>   second loop adds the sum of the first loop to the sum of the second
>   making the average wrong (Sum:34+22=56). I want it to be 22 so the
>   average for that would be 7

One approach is to reset the value of `sum` after you've printed the `sum` and `average` to the console.

**Example:**

```
int n;
int average;
int sum = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        System.out.println("Number is :" + n);
        sum += n;
    }
    average = sum / 3;

    System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
    sum = 0;
}
```

or to make life easier you can make the variable `sum` local within the loop so that at each iteration the value of `sum` will reset to default value:

**Example:**

```
int n;
int average = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        System.out.println("Number is :" + n);
        sum += n;
    }
    average = sum / 3;

    System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum += n;` inside the second `for` loop keeps on incrementing the value of `sum` (even the older sum values from loop). Thus you need to reset the value of `sum` to 0 every time at the begineeing the first loop.

```
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
   sum = 0;
   //rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

You must clean the `sum` variable after the first loop:

```
//..
int sum;

for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
    sum = 0; // -------> Here it is necessary to be clean for the next iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        System.out.println("Number is :" + n);
        sum += n;
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total sum I suggest adding a second `iterationSum` variable to add up the 3 numbers. Something like:

```
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
    int iterationSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ...
        iterationSum += n;
    }
    average = iterationSum / 3;
    ...
}
```

If you don't care about the total sum just reset you sum to 0 in each iteration:

```
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
    sum = 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 2;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n;
    int average;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
        sum=0;// this makes the trick
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
            System.out.println("Number is :" + n);
            sum += n;
        }
        average = sum / 3;

    System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

    }

}
```